# "Не брать кредиты" или "не брать кредитов"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, склонение

Как правильно: *не брать **кредитов*** или  *не брать **кредиты***?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Оба варианта правильны. Первый (не брать кредитов) более свойственен разговорной речи, бытовым разговорам. Второй - более официальный.

Вообще выбор падежа (винительный или родительный) при отрицании глагола определяется многими факторами, все их здесь перечислять нет особого смысла, но одним из моментов является противопоставление конкретного (*не брать кредиты* - вот эти, что предлагают) и общего (*не брать кредитов* - вообще никаких).

Comment: Наоборот, винительный падеж является более разговорным. Здесь перечислены случаи, когда родительный или винительный падеж является предпочтительным при глаголах с отрицанием, весьма любопытно: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/67-otr.

Answer (score 0):

Корректно: **Не брать *(что?)* кредиты**.